# Fatal error in initialization of genesis.json file

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, genesis

I am using geth 1.6.7 stable release. During initialization of genesis block for priavte network it throws an error which is

> Fatal: invalid genesis file: invalid character '"' after object key:value pair

**My genesis.json**

```
{
 "nonce": "0x0000000000000042",
 "mixhash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
 "difficulty": "0x400",
 "alloc": {},
 "coinbase": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
 "timestamp": "0x00",
 "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
 "extraData": "ChainSkills Genesis Block",
 "gasLimit": "0xffffffff"
 "config": {
    "chainId": 59,
    "homesteadBlock": 0,
    "eip155Block": 0,
    "eip158Block": 0
 }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried leaving out alloc ?

Comment: @NikitaFuchs i removed the alloc but still it did not work

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the comma after the gas limit line. ;)

Comment: I did that before I got this error " Fatal: invalid genesis file: json: cannot unmarshal hex string of odd length into Go struct field Genesis.extraData of type hexutil.Bytes " although I change extraData field value to "0x0"

Comment: Altough this is another question, I remember having to remove 0x here and there, as they are only data type indicators.

Comment: Thanks Nikita Fauchs , i solved it by removing the zero after x in the extraData value